# problem with displaying image from php in windows

Tags: php, windows, image, character-encoding, readfile

I'm trying to display an image using php:

```
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header('Content-length: '.filesize($IMAGE));
readfile($IMAGE);
```

Bu the image is not showing up on a WAMP server if the .php file which contains this block of code is saved as utf-8 (otherwise it works). I tested it on a LAMP server and it works.

My question is: how can I make this work on windows without changing the charset of the file?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're saving as UTF-8, and using Notepad, note that Notepad will put a unicode BOM (byte order marker) at the start of the file, which is 2 bytes of otherwise invisible data. This will screw up your download, as the BOM will count as output.

Comment: Thanks. It seems like this was the problem (although the file wasn't saved with Notepad). Strange it worked on a server running Linux.